# DreamFactory: How to upload an image to the fileserver and save the path of the image in DataBase?

Tags: database, post, save, store, dreamfactory

I'm thinking about using DreamFactory as API. I'm fresh in serversice-logic. I want to store an image on the filesystem and the path of the stored file into a database. I won't store the image as blob inside the database, because their will be many other images following. Can anybody please point me into the right direction?

First post the image to the filesystem using:

```
post /files/{file_path}
```

And after that:

```
post /mysql/_table/{table_name} createRecords() - Create one or more records
```

But how to pass the path to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use server-side scripting (V8Js in this case) on the POST to /files/{file_path}. Go to the Admin application, Scripts tab, and work your way through the events to the following path...

```
Process Event Scripts > files > files.{file_path} > [POST] files.{file_path} > files.{file_path}.post.post_process
```

Try the following script...

```
// event.resource is the {file_path} part, 
// including any folders from root, i.e. my/path/file.txt
var_dump(event.resource); 

// Create a record that you want to post to a table, 
// using the "todo" table for example, setting "name" to the file path
// "mysql" is my db service name
var record = {"resource": [ {"name": event.resource, "complete": false } ] }; 
var result = platform.api.post('mysql/_table/todo', record);

var_dump(result); 
// result contains a resource array with the id of the record created
// like {"resource": [ {"id": 5} ] }
```

Comment: Thx a lot, and just for understanding: the script gets fired automatically after executing a POST files.{file_path} (couldn't test it yet)? And a 2nd one: it is overwritten for the entire installation then, isn't it ( I mean, can I use this script for one app only)?

Comment: Yes, events, and thus any active scripts applied to that event, get fired automatically, "pre_" before the service handles the POST and "post_" afterwards. 2nd one: Yes, but you could check for api_key that applies to a particular app, by using the event.request.headers 'x-dreamfactory-api-key' (or parameters 'api_key' based on how you pass your keys.

Comment: I got another issue: I tried this script, but it is never triggered. Is this a known bug, or am I missing something? I enabled error logging and it works fine in custom scripts, but not with the scripts from the scripts tab.

Comment: UPDATE: It just isn't working for the filestorage's scripts. Tried the same for mysql .get.post_process and it worked there.

Comment: UPDATE 2 : Only v8js isn't working. I rewrote this in php and the data is written in the database. If trying your code, the error is: syntax error : ;  .

Comment: How did you install and what version are you running?

Comment: I'm running a local version (the bitnami installer) on windows. I just updated from 2.0.4-2 to 2.1, but still got this error.

Comment: You mentioned the mysql one working, so v8js is working. Make sure the "active" flag is checked in your script. Can you check the dreamfactory log and see if there is further details there?, let's focus on v8js, as php scripts behave a bit differently.

Comment: local.ERROR: Exception executing javascript: files.{file_path}.post.post_process:8: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;